# Play framework's route always calls the default one

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

I have the following routes defined:

```
GET /practiceexams      controllers.content.ExamController.allExams
GET /practiceexams/:id  controllers.content.ExamController.allExamsForTechnology(id: Int)
```

My URL to the second route looks like:

```
http://localhost:9000/practiceexams?id=1000
```

But for some reason that I can't fathom, the call always lands in the default url which is /practiceexams. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified the `id` in the second route to be a path parameter, but your URL uses it as a query parameter. That's not good.

Try this:

`http://localhost:9000/practiceexams/1000`

This route defines `id` as a path parameter:

```
GET /practiceexams/:id  controllers.content.ExamController.allExamsForTechnology(id: Int)
```

This route defines `id` as a query parameter:

```
GET /practiceexams  controllers.content.ExamController.allExamsForTechnology(id: Int)
```

See the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaRouting) for more details.